# Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags

Tags: linux, server, filesystems, nfs, nas

NOW, I'm working with NFS with Linux OS

here is the thing.
when I'm handling with some file attribute job, I can handle it in a local status
but, when I get in NFS status I get
**lsattr:Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags**
**chattr:Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags**

Is there any alternative command or solution?

※ except chomod or chwon I'm willing to get several command that is very same with chattr & lsattr

thanks for all helps....

I tried different mount optinos (ex. noac nfs4_acl, nocto)

Comment: please see site for questions about using Linux https://serverfault.com/q/324975/115396

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.